# Both axes labels and frame to my graph

Tags: graphics

Seems like I can't ad axes labels  and a frame to my graph.

I am trying this:

```
Plot[Blackvolality[k], {k, 0, 0.1}, AxesLabel -> {Volatility, Strike},
PlotLabel -> "Beta=0"]
```

This work fine^. But when I add frame to it:

```
Plot[Blackvolality[k], {k, 0, 0.1}, AxesLabel -> {Volatility, Strike},
PlotLabel -> "Beta=0",Frame->True]
```

Suddenly my Axes labels disappear. How Come? How can I have both?

Comment: Have you seen `FrameLabel`?

Comment: No I hadn't. But now I have and it solves my problem, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:
Add this to your code

```
FrameLabel->{Strike,Volatility}
```